# Java finding which image I clicked?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, mouseevent

Scenario: I have one `JFrame` and `JPanel` added to that `JFrame`. on this panel, I have drawn 3 images using:

```
public void paint(graphics g) { 
     g.drawImage(img1,100,100,null);
     g.drawImage(img2,200,200,null);
     g.drawImage(img3,300,300,null);
}
```

I have implemented `MouseListener` interface to listen clicks.  Now, I want that whenever I click any of these images my output(on command prompt using `System.out.println();`) should be the image object which I have clicked?

Please explain me is it possible and how?

Comment: You seem to be drawing the images one on top of the other -- is that correct? And you should do all drawing in the JPanel's paintComponent, not paint. Even better would be to use JLabels that hold ImageIcons.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: you are right..probably the best should be use JLabels and attach a mouse listener for each one. I let you write this solution :)

Comment: @Heisenbug: You go ahead and add it as an option to your answer. I've enough points. 1+ for your answer by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first of all you are drawing all your images at (0,0), are you sure you want to do that? If you do that is possible that you click a point that belongs to all your images (es, 0,0).

By the way, inside your MouseListener you have this method:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    Point point = e.getPoint();
}
```

point store the coordinate of your click relative to the component you are listening to.
So what you have to do is simply to check if the point where you click is inside image area. You can do the following:

```
Rectangle imageBounds = new Rectangle(x,y,image_width, image_height);
if (imageBounds.contains(point)){
    //point is inside given image
}
```

where x,y are the coordinate where you are drawing your image with drawImage method(0,0 in your case) and image_width, image_height are the dimension of your image.

EDIT:

there is an alternative to the solution I explained above. Like suggested by Hovercraft Full Of Eels you can do the following:

1. create a JLabel for each image you have want to display
2. use JLabel's [setIcon()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) method to specify the image that will be displayed on each label.
3. Add your labels to your JPanel
4. add a mouse listener to each JLabel

This approach has a great benefit: you don't have to worry about mouse coordinates because each JLabel has it's relative mouse listener.
The only one thing that you should consider is the following:

using Component instead of drawing your images, you won't be able to absolute poisiotion them, but you have to use an appropiate LayoutManager to layout your JLabel.

Comment: that was typo!! drawing at (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for a simple card game I was working on:

1. Optional: Make an object to represent your clickable image. It should know it's (x, y), width/height, and how to draw itself on the screen.
2. Keep a reference to all of your clickable images in a collection (e.g. List).
3. Create a method to determine if the position of the user's click is within the boundaries of your clickable image (I put this in the object created from #1).
4. On mouseClicked (or other applicable methods in your listener), traverse your collection of images and call **wasClicked()**, which might look something like this:

   ```
   public boolean wasClicked( int x, int y ) {

       return( x > getX() && x < ( getX() + getWidth() ) && 
               y > getY() && y < ( getY() + getHeight() ) );

   }
   ```

Your implementation may vary. Alternatively you can also extend a JComponent and add a MouseListener to that, but for reasons which I can't recall at the moment, the above worked better for me in my case.